# How are folk storing lots of Files on Cases?

Tags: civicase, attachments, files

I know there are File fields on Activities, and we can add File Fields to the case itself.

But say there are 20 documents to add over time.

while googling I found this which sounds interesting https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.documents since their roadmap talks about searching by 'case type'

Comment: They often come in via email so get filed via the email processor as activities, but it doesn't provide any structure. Although I have once used the email processor hook to change the activity type, making them a little more findable.

Comment: Emailing with the attachment can get it added directly to the case?

Comment: I think the docs (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/case-management/set-up/#filing-emails-on-cases) used to describe it more fully but yes if somebody replies to an email sent from Manage Case it will recognize the thing in square brackets. You can also manually add the square brackets code to the subject before sending. Unfortunately it's a code instead of the case id, which I think was originally a misunderstanding. If interested I can post somewhere the override code I've used to make it recognize case id too. There is also a manual File-On-Case action on non-case activities.

Comment: Thanks i need to read up on this more. we already have sites where incoming emails are creating Activities - but not done it for replies.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not the fact that it's a reply per se, it's the fact that the subject of an email processed by the email processor contains square brackets with a code that matches the code for an existing case, e.g. subject = "Re: Batman [#a1b3c]".

Answer (score 2):

There are different solutions as you suggested. One is using custom fields of the type file upload or use activities. 
There is indeed a document extension and this is one also capable of storing documents on a case. The advantage of the latter is that it could also store versions of the same document.

It is not yet possible to search for documents on a case.

Comment: I really like the look of what the civicoop Documents extension offers. thanks to you and the clients who funded it. i expect we will find some ways to contribute back to the project.

Answer (score 2):

We did end up using [Documents](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.documents) - we added quite a few new features to it to extend its capabilities which you can read about [here](https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/using-and-improving-the-documents-extension-a-drupal-extension-by-civicoop)